# Lightbox overtop of Quicktime embed?

Tags: lightbox, quicktime

I have a site where I am using [Litebox](http://www.doknowevil.net/litebox/) to display images. On pages with QuickTime embeds the box appears below the movie. How can I get the box to appear on top? I tried setting wmode=transparent but, while it works in Webkit browsers and IE, it fails in Gecko browsers.

Comment: The browser is rendering it below the movie, not embedding.  Just hide the movie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I lightbox or render anything over a select box, I have to hide the select box via display:none.  This prevents the select box from rendering over top of whatever I'm rendering in IE 6 (maybe 7 and 8 too, not sure).

You may have to do the same thing to the quicktime embed in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that approach; it works relatively well. Only in IE, however, does hiding/showing the video not restart it.